# C++ В массиве какого типа удобнее всего сохранять IP Адрес?

Tags: c++, сокет

У меня есть несколько IP адресов:

```
192.168.0.2 ,
192.168.0.3 ,
192.168.0.4 ,
192.168.0.5
```

Эти IP адреса нужно записать в массив my_ip_address[4].
Но какого типа должен быть массив my_ip_address[4], чтобы было удобно и без ошибок работать с ним?

Comment: `uint32_t` -- это, естественно, для IPv4

Answer (score 1):

Традиционно IPv4 адрес представляется в виде `unsigned int`, либо просто `int` (см. например, функцию PHP `ip2long`). Представление в виде знакового целого создает некоторые проблемы при сортировке, так что оптимальнее всего `unsigned int`.

Преобразование IP<->int:

- [IP Address to Integer - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680622/ip-address-to-integer-c)
- [Conversion of IP address to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283703/conversion-of-ip-address-to-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от того, в каком виде Вы потом используете информация об адресах. Храните в том виде, в котором потом используете, то есть вставляете в вызов функций.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите сэкономить память (для четырех адресов - неактуально), то массив из `uint32_t` подойдет (четыре числа от 0 до 255 - это как раз четыре байта).

Другой вариант, попроще - массив из `std::string`.

Comment: А если IP адресов будет больше, чем 4? Допустим 100. Какой тип лучше использовать тогда?

Comment: @Glonge Смотря что вы с ними делаете. Попробуйте оба варианта, замеряйте время и потребление памяти. Тогда сможете точно узнать, что лучше в вашем случае.

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что хотите получить. Bообще должно быть удобно работать с

```
vector<string>
```

Правда ето не подходит если вы собираетесь обрабатывать их как числа. 
 тогда советую сделать так.

1) прочитать адрес как строку

2) разбить по точкам и получить на выходе массив строк

3) потом всё просуммировать таким макаром

***Пример*** `192.168.0.2`

```
192* 100000 + 168*100 +0*10+ 2 = 19216802
```

а потом в `vector<int>my_ip_address`

Comment: а что из себя представляет `vector`? Ну я имел виду, если string отвечает за строку, а vector?

Comment: Вектор по сути тотже массив, только с НАМНОГО боллее гибкой структурой.

Comment: массив на понтах))) Спасибо, понял

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал какое-нибудь такое объединение:

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char parts[4];
    unsigned int whole;
} IPAddress;
```